# UniformJS Causes Fields to Dissappear

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress

I recently placed the UniformJS (http://uniformjs.com/) script on a webpage in order to style the SELECT and UPLOAD fields. I set the script to affect those fields, however, now the fields have completely disappeared. Here is how I have the script set up:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function(){
    $("input, select").uniform();
  });
</script>
```

Here is the webpage (notice the Resume and Country fields missing, as well as some radio boxes):
http://goo.gl/aJKv1

I went into the UniformJS stylesheet and changed all of the filepaths to absolute files, just to be sure it wasn't a linking error - but still no luck.

I'm still extremely new to Javascript/jQuery, but I've tried everything I can think of.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css is missing.

Here is the console output:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.mcfaddengavender.net/newmg/contact/careers/www.mcfaddengavender.net/newmg/wp-content/themes/custom/js/css/uniform.default.css`

You forgot the `http://`.
Change Your link to this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mcfaddengavender.net/newmg/wp-content/themes/custom/js/css/uniform.default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">`